# SQL Remove IDs that contain value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently facing a problem where I have to display a list of Orders without the use of the join function.

The problem I face is selecting the OrderNumber that does not contain 'Fish'

The current code I have still gives me the first order since part of the order does not contains 'Fish'

```
SELECT OrderNumber FROM Table1
WHERE DishID IN
(SELECT DishID FROM Table2
WHERE DishName NOT LIKE '%Fish%')
```

The tables I have are as follows:
[Sorry im not sure why the table isnt showing but here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGfaC.jpg)

Table1

```
| OrderNumber| DishID |
| ---------- | ------ |
| A100001    | 1      |
| A100001    | 3      |
| A100002    | 2      |
```

Table2

```
| DishID | DishName|
| ------ | ------  |
| 1      | Fish    |
| 2      | Chicken |
| 3      | Beef    |
```

Comment: JOIN isn't a function but anyway, why is its use prohibited?

Answer (score 0):

For that  you can query table1 twice

So that you exclude al  order numbers, that have any fish dish in it.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table2
>     (`DishID` varchar(6), `DishName` varchar(7))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table2
>     (`DishID`, `DishName`)
> VALUES
>     ('1', 'Fish'),
>     ('2', 'Chicken'),
>     ('3', 'Beef')
> ;
>
>
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     (`OrderNumber` varchar(10), `DishID` varchar(6))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table1
>     (`OrderNumber`, `DishID`)
> VALUES
>
>     ('A100001', '1'),
>     ('A100001', '3'),
>     ('A100002', '2')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     `OrderNumber`
> FROM
>     table1
> WHERE
>     `OrderNumber` NOT IN (SELECT 
>             `OrderNumber`
>         FROM
>             table1
>         WHERE
>             `DishID` IN (SELECT 
>                     `DishID`
>                 FROM
>                     table2
>                 WHERE
>                     `DishName` = 'Fish'))
> ```
>
> ```
> | OrderNumber |
> | :---------- |
> | A100002     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b7a93b348ba6ca26a2e7afd703226e56)*